# Cannot build apk-file for Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build, apk

I’m trying to build an apk-file for Android with Unity but I always get an error-message like the one below.

[image: Build failure message]

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Developer/SDKs/Android/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar" -

Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00207] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:172 
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

These are my specifications: Unity 2017.1f3, minimum api level 16, target api level 23.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Android manifest merge error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386122/unity-android-manifest-merge-error)

Comment: Ah. Ok. I will check this out immediately.